# ServiceStack/Redis with Json over Http returns string not Json

Tags: json, web-services, f#, redis, servicestack

I am trying to get CouchDB-like response from Redis -  by using ServiceStack WebServices to access data stored via ServiceStack .Net RedisTypedClient onto Redis.

Now the web services are described as providing a CouchDB layer onto Redis. However, unlike equivalent CouchDB calls to a CouchDB, I never get back json but only strings *- to be clear I do get back json but with the payload is in string format.*

This applies to getting items from Redis List, Set and HashSet collections. All the items via either the xml,json or csv web services always deliver the payload as a string.  Now I can see the serialized form of the type I stored in the string  - such as a json array of strings or whatever, but the *data* is not delivered as json (or csv or xml) but as a string. I cannot find a query flag (.e.g. 'format=json' say)  in any of the autogenerated documentation for these web services -which does say it delivers the payload as a string which is what I see.

Further apart from using the default jsv serializer through RedisTypedCLient I also tried  directly calling the ServiceStack json serializer to serialize as json not jsv and also the Newtonsoft json serializer. None of this makes any difference. I did not expect it too as I imagine the default services would likely only manage the expected jsv version and would deliver anything else as strings. However I did not expect this of the internal serialization format.

So is it possible to get CouchDB like json responses from ServiceStack/Redis/Builtin-WebServices?

**Update**

Here is a typical query via the ServiceStack json web service:

http://myserver.com/redis/json/syncreply/GetAllItemsFromList?id=test

This is a Redis List collection containing strongly typed items:

```
type TestItem( gr,eType,pillar,offset) =
    let mutable _gr     = gr    
    let mutable _eType  = eType 
    let mutable _pillar = pillar
    let mutable _offset = offset
    member x.Gr     with get()= _gr     and set(v) = _gr     <- v
    member x.EType  with get()= _eType  and set(v) = _eType  <- v
    member x.Pillar with get()= _pillar and set(v) = _pillar <- v
    member x.Offset with get()= _offset and set(v) = _offset <- v
    override x.ToString() = sprintf "%s %s %s %M" x.Gr x.EType x.Pillar x.Offset
```

The list collection was added using IRedisTypedClient Interface/API and I am expecting back a json list of json objects - a set of key/value pairs each  pair corresponding to one of the four public properties in the type above. Instead I get

```
{"Items":["   {\"Gr\":\"BON13\",\"EType\":\"MARKET\",\"Pillar\":\"BON3.R0\",\"Offset\":0.0}","{\"Gr\":\"BOQ13\",\"EType\":\"MARKET\",\"Pillar\":\"BOQ3.R0\",\"Offset\":0.0}","{\"Gr\":\"BOU13\",\"EType\":\"MARKET\",\"Pillar\":\"BOU3.R0\",\"Offset\":0.0}","{\"Gr\":\"BOV13\",\"EType\":\"SETTLEPILLAR\",\"Pillar\":\"BOU3.R0\",\"Offset\":0.0}","{\"Gr\":\"BOZ16\",\"EType\":\"SETTLEPILLAR\",\"Pillar\":\"BOU3.R0\",\"Offset\":0.0}"],"ResponseStatus":{}}
```

In other words a string representation of the json object not the json object itself.

So again, how can I get back, in this case, a json list of of json objects rather than a json list of strings. (And the same goes for Sets, Dictionaries and more basic keyed json documents  a la other NoSql dbs)?

I have the same issues getting back csv - it comes back as a string rather than either a csv of key/value pairs or a csv of keys and values and in XML where this,again, comes back as a string not not an XML format of key/value pairs.

**Update 1**

It does not need to be a strongly typed as above. It could be a list of a list of strings. In which case I get back a json list of strings rather than a json list containing items comprising json list of string.

**Update 2**
Whilst the problem clearly seems to be in the ServiceStack webservice implementation not being like CouchDB although *it claims it is*, here is some sample code to put the data into Redis via ServiceStack.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open ServiceStack.Redis
open System.Linq

type Repository() =       
    static let mutable __port = 6379         
    static let mutable __host = "myserver.com"
    static let mutable __client = new RedisClient(__host,__port) 
    static member Client = __client :> IRedisClient

type Repository<'T>() = 
    let _client = Repository.Client
    member x.GetList key =
        use client = _client.As<'T>()
        match _client.GetEntryType key with
        | RedisKeyType.List -> 
            client.Lists.Item key |> client.GetAllItemsFromList 
        | _ -> new List<'T>()    
    member x.SetList (key, values: List<'T>) =
        if (values.Count <> 0) then
            use client = _client.As<'T>()
            let list = client.Lists.Item key
            values |> Seq.iter (fun x -> client.AddItemToList(list, x))
```

Usage

```
 let repo = new Repository<List<string>>
 let items = [["key0";"data0"];["key1";"data1"]]
             |> Seq.map (fun kd -> List.init kd ))
             |> List.init
 repo.SetList("test",items)
```

The is just a cut and paste of longer code. I have tried this in c#, f# and with non default serialization as already stated. That is I have tried six different methods to date and none delivered the *data payload* as json objects via ServiceStack WebServices only as strings.

Comment: There is no code to show. The question is about the standard responses of the built-in ServiceStack json  webservice calls that produce strings not json. I want to know how to get it to provide json e.g presumably some flag that is not in the auto documentation.

Comment: Why do you say that it returns a string? Can you at least add the URL you are using and the response you receive? Could it be that the service returns a json object but your browser renders it as a string?

Comment: I am looking at this via various non .Net/ServiceStack tools, such as  browser json parsers extensions and via excel. None recognise the data as json only as a string. These are the same tools I use to succesfully process json output from CouchDb.

Comment: Try this site to parse the JSON, just to see if it's valid: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: This site just confirms the issue that I am getting back strings rather than json objects. See the expanded question

Comment: If all formats return an unexpected result, you should probably check the stored value and the code you used to store it. The returned value IS a Json object, just not the one you expected. It has two properties, the first of which is an array with 5 text values. For whatever reason, each of the items stored in the Items array in your source code was stored as a string. Can you show the code you used to store the data?

Comment: Thre is nothing to show as the main way to code this is to use IRedisTypedClient<T>.  As I said in the OP, I also tried using json serializers directly both ServiceStacks' and NewtonSoft's. I can always get back the data correctly usng my f# .Net client whatever methods I use). However I do not expect the default ServiceStack webservices to magically know about the payload if it is in not the preferred ServiceStack format as genereated by IRedisTypedClient<T>. The issue here is over ServiceStacks's webservices failing to generate the expected json.

Comment: I'm assuming your service is returning a response object along the lines of: 

type TestResponse() =
    let mutable items = List.empty<TestItem>
    member this.Items with get() = items and set(itm) = items <- itm

??

Comment: In the above example T is List<string>. I get the type back that is put so in general a List<T> always successfully deserialized. This is nothing to do with the .Net client which works fine both ways  and everything to do with the ServiceStack web services that does not deserialize its stored as a string jsv into valid json. Can anyone confirm that they do get back the correct response from the ServiceStack webservices? The xml service says it will deliver a string value, I want to know how to do it in xml too.

Comment: If your response DTO specifies List<string> then ServiceStack is going to serialize your data into a List of strings. It's not the ServiceStack webservice that's the problem, it's the serializer - but it sounds like the serializer is doing exactly what it's being told to do. Try changing your response DTO to return a List<TestItem>. I am successfully using ServiceStack to return valid JSON objects over on my C# based services. I can't claim experience with F# but it works perfectly fine in C#, but again, I'm specifying my response types the way I described above.

Comment: I am trying to use the *default* ServiceStack webservices that are *claimed* to deliver CouchDB-like responses. *If this is not the case* then you are saying that I need to hand roll DTOs for each type for each webservice? This would be a serious problem given the number of types I am serializing. So can anyone confirm that the *default* is what is to be expected - delivering strings not json objects for the RedisTypedClient<T> API and so giving the same results as the RedisClient API which, by design, is meant to return strings. That is this  does not provide CouchDB-like web services?

Comment: MikeP I am talking about the ServiceStack default web services. I have no problem with either the c# or f# .net clients - everything is being serialized and deserialized as expected. So are you talking about the webservices?

Comment: MikeP if your comment was in response to my code added recently in the OP> then I am *not* getting back List<String> but a string containing a json equivalent of List<String> not the direct json equivalent itself. That is the problem specifically with the default webservices

Answer (score 1):

JSON data, when serialized and sent over the wire, is just a string. Your client needs to be JSON aware and de-serialize it into your object. The JsonClient for C# within ServiceStack is more than capable of handling this, and so are the many JavaScript frameworks that assist with AJAX calls (jQuery, AngularJS, etc).

Comment: I am using client aware json tools as noted in the above comment and these tools work fine with CouchDB and the many other json over http servies that I consume. None of these tools work with the output from Redis/ServiceStack as it is delivered as a string not json with e.g doubled quotes and escaped quotes in the payload - how do I get the ServiceStack return values as json?

Comment: Some example responses would be helpful to troubleshoot - right now I'm running a ServiceStack service and am not having any trouble with the JSON it returns.

Comment: See the expanded question.